# wp get meta data from post id in external file

Tags: php, wordpress

If I have my post ID in wordpress site, and I've to show yoast in another extra file in another domain that add in same hosting, I included wp-config.php file in external file, And i have to show meta tags, like title, description etc, so how can I do ?

```
<?php
require_once( dirname(__DIR__) . '/gag/wp-config.php');
echo get_post_meta($ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true)
```

But it returns null

Answer (score 2):

You need to require `wp-load.php` rather than `wp-config.php` - wp-config will only load the configuration variables and settings (it will be loaded automatically as part of wp-load's routines).

So, try this instead:

```
<?php
require_once( dirname(__DIR__) . '/gag/wp-load.php');
echo get_post_meta($ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true)
```

For more background, see [this Q&A on Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files).

Comment: Is there any file to include to activate/inlude plugins ?

Comment: That file should do it. I am of course assuming you have `$ID` defined, and that meta key exists.... otherwise, is `WP_DEBUG` on? Any errors? Can you successfully output things other than this meta key?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting permalink, and other info successfully

Comment: Ok, so Wordpress is loading correctly for you. Is that meta key in your database?

Comment: I hope so, BTW Now I'm using crawling to get info, thank you all :D

Answer (score 0):

You need only wp-load.php this also includes wp-config.php, please check your post meta by

```
print_r(get_post_meta($ID));
```

So, that you can get the exact idea and also make sure you are passing right $ID

```
<?php 
      require_once( dirname(__DIR__) . '/gag/wp-config.php');
      require_once( dirname(__DIR__) . '/gag/wp-load.php');
      echo get_post_meta($ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true)
```

Comment: `get_post_meta($ID, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true)` still returns nulll

Comment: Is there any file to include to activate/inlude plugins ?

Comment: wp-load loads wp-config for you :)

Comment: BTW I tried, but I tired, Now I'm using crawling to get info, thank you all :D